# Bad response when try install opcache

Tags: centos6, php5, zend, opcache

**I have problem for install zendopcache**

I try 1 time and other and always have the same result i don´t know what it´s bad because this can install with php 5.6 , thanks and also i delete and clean yum etc and the same response

```
>  [root@cp ~]# yum install php-pecl-zendopcache
>     Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
>     Setting up Install Process
>     Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
>     Excluding mirror: mirror.de.leaseweb.net
>     Excluding mirror: mirror.nl.leaseweb.net
>      * epel: mirror.23media.de
>     Resolving Dependencies
>     --> Running transaction check
>     ---> Package php-pecl-zendopcache.x86_64 0:7.0.5-2.el6 will be installed
>     --> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20090626 for package: php-pecl-zendopcache-7.0.5-2.el6.x86_64
>     --> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20090626 for package: php-pecl-zendopcache-7.0.5-2.el6.x86_64
>     --> Finished Dependency Resolution
>     Error: Package: php-pecl-zendopcache-7.0.5-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
>                Requires: php(zend-abi) = 20090626
>                Installed: php-common-5.6.33-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php56)
>                    php(zend-abi) = 20131226-64
>                Available: php-common-5.3.3-49.el6.x86_64 (base)
>                    php(zend-abi) = 20090626
>     Error: Package: php-pecl-zendopcache-7.0.5-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
>                Requires: php(api) = 20090626
>                Installed: php-common-5.6.33-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php56)
>                    php(api) = 20131106-64
>                Available: php-common-5.3.3-49.el6.x86_64 (base)
>                    php(api) = 20090626
>      You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
>      You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
>     [root@cp ~]#
```

I try many times and i try all and i don´t know what i can do for fix this, thanks for the help

Actually in server use Centos 6 64 bits, and run php 5.6

Answer (score 1):

Zend OPcache is [included with PHP 5.5 and later](http://php.net/manual/en/opcache.installation.php) (and as from Remi) and is already installed on your system. You do not need to install the [PECL package](https://pecl.php.net/package/ZendOpcache), which is only for PHP 5.5 or earlier.

If for some reason OPcache is not installed, try installing the `php-opcache` package from Remi.

Comment: but how configurate because i don´t see inside  library as extension.so

Comment: On my system there is an `/etc/php.d/10-opcache.ini` which you can customize if you wish. See my edits.

Comment: it´s very strange i upgrade from 5.3 yo 5.6 without problems and in that folder no exists that file, the other .ini yes, i must create or howewer when upgrade must create this 10-opcache.ini, and no see in library the extension .so, yes other extensions, what do you think about this and what i must do in this case , thank´s